# How to convert .eml to .msg in java for free

Tags: java, apache-poi, mapi

Requirement
We are calling API..The API need .msg file in request.

Logic
I have .eml file in my local diskspace, I want to convert into .msg in java for free.
Code Snippet :

String msg_file_path="C:\temp\msg_email.msg";

FileOutputStream msg_file = new FileOutputStream(msg_file_path);

try {

MAPIMessage msgObj = new MAPIMessage("C:\temp\_emai.eml");

msgObj.write(msg_file);

System.out.println("EML file converted to MSG: " + msg_file);

}

catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

Getting below error:

rg.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x6465766965636552, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

Answer (score 1):

The error is very specific - you are feeding the converter class a text file as if it were MSG. `6465766965636552` is `"devieceR"`, so yes, it is definitely not an MSG file.

Open it in Notepad to see what kind of data you have.